# Hibernate - In a one-to-many relationship, a child loses references to the parent when updating

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, cascade

As in the title, when performing the update operation, the previous child loses the reference to the parent.

Parent side

```
@OneToMany(cascade =CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "individual_id")
private List<ContactMedium> contactMedium;
```

Children side

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contactMedium")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ContactMedium 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id ;

    @ManyToOne
    private Individual individual;
```

Patch operation

```
 public Individual patch(Individual individual, Long id) {
        Individual objectToSave = individual;
        objectToSave.setId(id);
        return individualRepository.save(objectToSave);
    }
```

When updating, the previous property loses references to the child. How can I prevent this?

[image]

Comment: maybe it is the problem with fetch = FetchType.LAZY?

Comment: Why do you need to update the id when you are updating the parent?

Comment: I dont want to update the id, I just need two references to my individual id

Comment: What do you mean by 'the previous child'? Is the 'previous child' missing from the list when you're making the update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mappings seems wrong. Ideally they should be as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contactMedium")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ContactMedium 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id ;

    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinColumn
    private Individual individual;
```

and

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "individual", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ContactMedium> contactMedium;
```

You need to save the `ContactMedium` and `Individual` will automatically be saved. Here `ContactMedium` has the foreign key reference to `Individual` (and that is what is depicted in your database table screenshot).

Comment: It didn't help, my writing is the opposite but it's not wrong

Comment: You have `individual_id` in `contact_medium` table right? And `individual` table doesnot have `contact_medium_id`?

Answer (score 0):

Often one use `mappedBy` as parameter to `@OneToMany` instead of `@JoinColumn` to make the relationship two-ways.

Can you please try to change

```
@OneToMany(cascade =CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "individual_id")
private List<ContactMedium> contactMedium;
```

to

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "individual", cascade =CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ContactMedium> contactMedium;
```

and see if that worked better?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is unchanged

Comment: OK... You might want to turn on logging of the generated sql and see when is different from the expected sql.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add the `@OneToMany(mappedBy="individual" , cascade =CascadeType.PERSIST)` and the `@JoinColumn` in the `@ManyToOne` as below:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "individual", cascade =CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<ContactMedium> contactMedium;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "individual_id")
private Individual individual;
```

Comment: It didn't help, my writing is the opposite but it's not wrong

Comment: can you try before update getting the list getcontactMedium and re-assign it to objectTosave, like : 'objectToSave.setContactMedium(individual.getContactMedium());'

Comment: ok I suggest to try with CascadeType.PERSIST instead or CascadeType.ALL

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve the entity from the database using the ID first and then update the specific fields and persist the updated entity back.